# vim scripting "i want replacement for tnext in cscope"

Tags: vim, cscope

i want to replace a :tnext command for cscope but it is not working as my expectation.

1) below figure shows code which is working as expected. i can reach to 2nd instance of symbols.

```
function MyCounter()

    if !exists("s:counter")
        let s:counter = 1
        echo "script executed for the first time"
    else
        let s:counter = s:counter + 1
        echo "script executed " . s:counter . " times now"
    endif
endfunction

nmap <space>w :ls<CR>
nmap <space>i :call MyCounter()
nmap <space>n :cs find s <C-R>=expand("<cword>")<CR><CR>2<CR>
```

2) below code which is not working

```
function MyCounter()
    if !exists("s:counter")
        let s:counter = 1
        echo "script executed for the first time"
    else
        let s:counter = s:counter + 1
        echo "script executed " . s:counter . " times now"
    endif
endfunction

nmap <space>w :ls<CR>
nmap <space>i :call MyCounter()
nmap <space>n :cs find s <C-R>=expand("<cword>")<CR><CR><C-R>=str2nr(s:counter)<CR>
```

The difference between 1 and 2 code snippet is =str2nr(s:counter)
i.e., dynamic calculation of n instance of symbol upon user press n

before pressing space+n i always press space+i

please suggest me why 2nd code snippet is not working .

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
nmap <space>n :exec "cs find s" expand("<cword>") "\| norm" str2nr(s:counter)
```

You seem to be using `<C-R>=str2nr...` in the normal mode, which will not work.

*Disclaimer*: I haven't been able to test whethr the above approach can even work.

**Edit**

You might want to use the `cscopetag` setting:

```
                        *cscopetag* *cst*
If 'cscopetag' set, the commands ":tag" and CTRL-] as well as "vim -t" will
always use |:cstag| instead of the default :tag behavior.  Effectively, by
setting 'cst', you will always search your cscope databases as well as your
tag files.  The default is off.  Examples: >
    :set cst
    :set nocst
```

This should give you a rich set of commands working with tags, which might give you ways to do what you want (`:tjump`, `:tnext` etc)

Comment: I think, the command would not solve the issue in question, since, in this case, the questioner wants to feed the counter and a carriage return as row characters operating the Cscope `find` command's interactive screen, not as a Normal mode command (more specifically, a counter which is useless without a command immediately following it).

Comment: yes you are correct i want to pass value to "Cscope find command interactive screen"

Comment: @ManjunathaCachar I remembered the `cscopetag` option (see edit)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by the attempt to queue for processing the characters
obtained as a result of an expression's evaluation.  It is necessary to make
the expression be an expression one (see `:help :map-<expr>`) or use the
`feedkeys()` function.  For ease of modification of the mapping, I would
recommend to use the first approach and change the mapping as follows.

```
:nnoremap <expr> <space>n ':cs find s '.expand('<cword>')."\r".s:counter."\r\r"
```

Comment: Hi ib,
let s:counter = 3 
:nnoremap <space>n ':cs find s '.expand('<cword>')."\r".s:counter."\r"
should show 3rd symbol of output of  "cs find  s debug_printf"
which is not showing.